# I keep getting an error message saying this.replaceState is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

Right now I have a school project to build an app on my phone. We are using React Native and Java. I want to make a button in the app that changes to a random color when pressed. This, however, doesn't work.

Here is some snippets of my code:

```
    export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {color: "#000000"}
}
  render() {

    let color = this.state.color;
  return (

...

<View>
          <Button
          onPress = {changecolor}
          title = "This button changes color when pressed"
          color = {color}/>
        </View>

...

numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"];

this.random = this.numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.numbers.length)];

function changecolor() {
  this.replaceState({color: String("#"+random+random+random+random+random+random)});
}
```

I also had a problem before that the button only becomes shades of gray and not any color. Any help please?

edit: I should've mentioned that I used this.setState previously and it had the same result

Answer (score 0):

```
  export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {color: "#000000"}
    }

    render() {

    let color = this.state.color;
    return (
    <View>
        <Button
        onPress = {this.changecolor}
        title = "This button changes color when pressed"
        color = {color}/>
    </View>


    numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"];

    this.random = this.numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.numbers.length)];

    changecolor() {
        this.replaceState({color: String("#"+random+random+random+random+random+random)});
    }
}
```

Comment: I probably should've mentioned that I did this before replaceState and it had the exact same result

Comment: your function gets called or not ?

Comment: I don't know what that means, I am kinda new to java

Comment: This is not Java.

Comment: make a cosole.log("hello...") in changecolor() function and check if it gets printed or not ?

Comment: @Boopiester check my edited answer replace this with your code it will work

Answer (score 0):

Is `changecolor` even a member of `HomeScreen` class? Doesn't look like it, considering that it's declared with `function` and no parsing errors are screaming at you. Make it a method, and better yet, an arrow function:

```
changecolor = () => {
  this.replaceState({color: String("#"+random+random+random+random+random+random)});
}
```

Comment: It wasn't before. I did this and it worked, but only once.